# Update query runs but not the fields are not updated in sql database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, session, md5

I have a update page which has the update form for email and password, i tried console logging to see if the email and address are transmitted in post method,and the details are transmitted to this page but still the data is not persisted, could some one please tell me why thank you !

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

    <?php

        //extract form values and assign to regular PHP variables
        $uemail=$_POST['email'];    
        $passW=$_POST['pass'];
        $upassword= md5($_POST['passW']);


    if(!isset($_SESSION['usermail'])) {
        header('Location: ../homepage.php');
    }

else{
include "connection.php";


$session=$_SESSION["useremail"];    

    $sql = "UPDATE users SET uemail = '$uemail', upassword = '$upassword' WHERE uemail = '$session'";

$_SESSION["useremail"]=$uemail; //setting new email in session

        header("Location:../homepage.php");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Start by enabling error reporting and proper error handling on the query. Do that, then tell us what you get back, if any errors.

Comment: Why are you using MD5 here? Aren't you aware that that hashing method's been broken and not safe to use anymore. You should learn how to use `password_hash()` and prepared statements too. Do you want your database to have just disappeared one day?

Comment: Where is the form for this? and do all sessions arrays have value?

Comment: You didn't even do anything with your query; did you know that? I'm voting this as a typographical error.

Answer (score -1):

try to concatinate the variables.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

    <?php

        //extract form values and assign to regular PHP variables
        $uemail=$_POST['email'];    
        $passW=$_POST['pass'];
        $upassword= md5($_POST['passW']);


    if(!isset($_SESSION['usermail'])) {
        header('Location: ../homepage.php');
    }

else{
include "connection.php";


$session=$_SESSION["useremail"];    

    $sql = "UPDATE users SET uemail = '".$uemail."', upassword = '".$upassword."' WHERE uemail = '".$session."'";

$_SESSION["useremail"]=$uemail; //setting new email in session

        header("Location:../homepage.php");
    }
?>
```

and always check your variables if it is correct.. always look to your codes..

Comment: What difference would changing them to `'".$var."'` possibly fix this? They both do the same thing.